# Best way for splitting GraphQL schema into different modules in express-graphql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I'm new to QraphQL and I found some best practices for module system in `apollo-server` but I can't find anything for `express-graphql`!

I'm using `GraphQLSchema` instead of `buildSchema`. and when I'm trying to split my code into different modules, it will sticks in NodeJs circular dependencies error (returns empty object).

As a GraphQL expert, which one do you recommend? `apollo-server` or `express-graphql`? and if you recommend `express-graphql`, which method do you recommend? `GraphQLSchema` or `buildSchema`?

and also what is the best way for **splitting my schema for every one of these methods**?

Comment: Working with `GraphQLSchema` should be fine. What is important is that if you recursion in your type system put the recursive types in a thunk (function without arguments) like so `type: () => RecursiveType` on both sides. Now this type can be undefined during definition time.

Comment: If you don't use ES modules but `require` it can be even trickier. Here you have to reference the whole module and refrain from destructuring early: `const rec = require('RecursiveType')`, `type: () => rec.RecursiveType`.

Comment: @Herku but the problem is just here! I'm getting empty object but I'm not using recursive types and I'm using thunk! but I'm still getting empty object error in graphiql

Comment: Then, this seems to be a problem unrelated to GraphQL and related to Node.js' module resolution algorithm. Without you sharing precisely how you import files and your file structure I don't think I can help you :(

Answer (score 0):

Using **apollo-server-express**, helped me to do many kinds of stuff like this one.